# Anyone tried piggy-backing one Wolf Roadlink on top of another?

Tags: road-bike, derailleur-rear

I want to get a 46t sprocket on my old 9 speed Shimano Deore derailleur. The Wolftooth Roadlink only allows for a 40t, could I double-up two Roadlinks and get that extra capacity, or...?

Comment: At that point you're introducing a lot of slop into the system and getting the rear derailleur much lower and further away from the high end (small cogs) of the cassette. It'd be an interesting experiment, but not something I'd rely on.

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to me. Plenty of room for extra problems. But I like the outside the box thinking.

Comment: I've not done it, but consider that you're decreasing chain engagement on your smaller cogs too.

Comment: You're probably right, it's a bridge too far! One roadlink is working well with my 12-36. I've got an 11-34 which I'm going to get a 40t add on from Fouriers. I'll drop the 11 and run it as a 13-40 which, against my 33 chain ring, should really be able to get me up a brick wall!

Comment: Have you considered a smaller little chain ring on the front ?

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, you could do this to enable the 46 but the 11,12,13t sprockets would be a long way from the derailleur in those gears as the derailleur isn't designed for that difference. Try to imagine the shape of the pyramid of the 11-32 and the 11-46.

Derailleurs are designed around specific pyramid slopes.

This could work fine on a 18-46 cassette that doesn't exist.